# Regexp finding duplicated character conditionally in incorrectly formatted JSON

Tags: python, json, regex

Suppose I have the following string:

```
example = '{"Hello": "world", "key_1": ""Double quote text"", "key_2", ""}'
```

This is not a properly created JSON object, thus when I try to load it:

```
json.loads(example)
```

I get an error
`JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 29 (char 28)`

I've obviously tried to `example.replace('""', '"')`, but this, fixes `key_1`, but breaks `key_2`.

How can I remove the double quote in `key_1`, without removing it from `key_2`?

Comment: But that's what I'm mentioning that breaks the other key, or maybe I'm understanding you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this pattern and python regex `sub`

```
re.sub(r"(\"\"([^\"]*)\"\")",r'"\2"',example)
```

this pattern will find any sets of `""string""` that have data between them and replace is it with a `"string"`

a cleaner pattern would be this:

```
'(\"{2}([^\"]*)\"{2})'
```

Comment: An even cleaner pattern would be `r'"("[^"]+")"'`, replace with `r'\1'`